# systemverilog- Polymorphism

Tags: oop, system-verilog

The output of the below code was-

This is class A

This is class A

But according to me the output should be-

This is class A

This is Extended class A

Because, after printing the first line, we are assigning object of type EA to object of type A-

EA my_a = my_ea;

and then when we do-
my_a.disp();

it should print-This is Extended class A

Please tell whether I am correct or not?

```
class A ; //class A
task disp (); 
$display(" This is class A "); 
endtask 
endclass 

class EA extends A ; //subclass EA 
task disp (); 
$display(" This is Extended class A "); 
endtask 
endclass 

program main ; 
EA my_ea; 
A my_a; 

initial 
begin 
my_a = new(); 
my_a.disp(); 

my_ea = new(); 
my_a = my_ea; 
my_a.disp(); 
end 
endprogram
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the task as virtual:

```
class A ; //class A
  virtual task disp (); 
    $display(" This is class A "); 
  endtask 
endclass
```

Comment: Ok. But why it is not printing -This is Extended class A, now? As I am assigning object of type EA to object of type A.

Comment: I does print "This is Extended class A" when implemented here: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/WcN